# Stuck on Graph API (facebook API), how do i get name, email and sex using this code?

Tags: php, html, json, facebook, graph

Well, this is the issue. I have this code, who works very well:

### The code

```
<?php

define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'MY.APP.CODE');
define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', 'MY.APP.SECRET');

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($cookie) {
      echo("The ID is: " . $cookie['uid']);
      echo('<br>The profile Picture is: <IMG SRC="http://graph.facebook.com/' . $cookie['uid'] . '/picture?type=large"><br>');
    } else {
      echo('<fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday,publish_stream,user_status"></fb:login-button>');
    } ?>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      FB.init({appId: '<?= FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>', status: true,
               cookie: true, xfbml: true});
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### The output

> The id is: *A number here* The picture
>   is: *A picture here*

### The problem

As you can see, this code give me the facebook's ID of the user and the profile picture when he login and give the permissions to the app. As i said, this code works fine, but i need more information, how do i retrive the email, the sex and the name using the same logic of this code?. Please do not use external libiries (like the *facebook.php*)

Remember that this is a very simple app so i dont want to get it complex in the code, i know that the solution have something to do with parsing JSON responses, but i cant find any good and simple code. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Graph API returns result as JSON.

For example

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/4 HTTP/1.1
```

gives

```
{"id":"4","name":"Mark Zuckerberg","first_name":"Mark","last_name":"Zuckerberg","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/zuck","gender":"male","locale":"en_US"}
```

Here `name` is name; `gender` is sex.  If you have granted email permission from user, you got the email also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at all the extended permissions that you may need to ask for based on what data you need.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
'me/friends?fields=gender,name,id'
```