# Get user's name from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to know how is it possible to retrieve a string from an external page.

For example: In a PHP website, the user sends a facebook id, ex: 1157251270

And the website returns the *name* from http://graph.facebook.com/1157251270.

I hope I made it clear.

Thank you

Comment: *(related)* [Stuck on Graph API (facebook API), how do i get name, email and sex using this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093548/stuck-on-graph-api-facebook-api-how-do-i-get-name-email-and-sex-using-this-co)

Comment: (related) [What is JSON and why would I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

Comment: I would read the Facebook TOS for this, just to be clear if your activity is legal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Graph API returns JSON strings, so you can use:

```
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/1157251270'))->name;
```

or more verbose:

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/1157251270');
$parsedJson  = json_decode($pageContent);
echo $parsedJson->name; // Romanos Fessas
```

See [`json_decode` — Decodes a JSON string](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Facebook's PHP SDK, you can also do this to query their graph API:

```
$fb = new Facebook();
$object = $fb->api('/1157251270');
```

Comment: @arslaanejaz Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 5):

you get it by:

```
$link = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/1157251270'));
echo $link->name;
```

Nice tut:
http://webhole.net/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/

Answer (score 2):

Either you use :

```
$res_json = file_gets_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/1157251270")
$res = json_decode($res_json)
```

Or, if you prefer curl (here with https and access token) :

```
$ch4 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/1157251270?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN");
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

if(!$result = curl_exec($ch4))
{
    echo curl_error($ch4);
} else {
    $res = json_decode($res_json)
}

curl_close($ch4);
```

Comment: If you require non-public information you will have to ask the user for permission, then use an access_token to view its informations

Answer (score 0):

For facebook data you can use `json_decode`.

For another sites try with webscraping, for example:
[here](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/web-scrape-with-php-tutorial)