# Retrieving Facebook name without any permissions

Tags: php, facebook, variables, web

I would like to know if there was any easy way of getting the name [as a variable in PHP], of a user that it is currently logged in on Facebook. Problem is, I don't want them to have to stay accepting anything like giving permission.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,
Tom.

P.S. Picture the most amateur PHP Programmer - I'm worse than him.

Comment: The problem is you can't know the user id on the first place. Unless you're able to access the user's cookies, then the user id is inside cookies file, example: .facebook.com TRUE / TRUE 0 c_user 12012345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can't get name without user ID , which needs a little permission
also you can check this question [Get user name from graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788937/get-users-name-from-facebook-graph-api)

Comment: So, how do you get the User ID?

Comment: You have to create Facebook app ,just go to
developers.facebook.com and create your own app ,
and use this sdk , it's official from facebook and comes with example.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk